# TableView didSelectRow could not perform as expected result

Tags: swift, realm, tableview, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

As per the video shown, I want the TransactionListViewController to show the cell selected from AccountViewController as selected.

However, TransactionViewController shows only Section 0 Row 0 & Section 0 Row 1, while others section & row keep showing Section 0 Row 1

**Expected Result**

Section 0, Row 0 will perform segue and pull data for Section 0, Row 0

Section 0, Row 1 will perform segue and pull data for Section 0, Row 1

Section 1, Row 0 will perform segue and pull data for Section 1, Row 0

Section 1, Row 1 will perform segue and pull data for Section 1, Row 1

Section 2, Row 0 will perform segue and pull data for Section 2, Row 0

Section 2, Row 1 will perform segue and pull data for Section 2, Row 1

[image]

```
#AccountTableViewController

 var accTypePA : Results<AccTypePA>?
 var accTypeCA : Results<AccTypeCA>?
 var accTypeInv : Results<AccTypeInv>?
 var accTypeAss : Results<AccTypeAss>?
 var accTypeLbty : Results<AccTypeLbty>?

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let strAccountPA = accTypePA
            selectedPA = strAccountPA?[indexPath.row]
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegToTransactionPage", sender: indexPath.row)

        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let strAccountCA = accTypeCA
            selectedCA = strAccountCA?[indexPath.row]
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegToTransactionPage", sender: indexPath.row)

        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            let strAccountCA = accTypeCA
            selectedCA = strAccountCA?[indexPath.row]
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegToTransactionPage", sender: indexPath.row)

        } else if indexPath.section == 3 {
            let strAccountCA = accTypeCA
            selectedCA = strAccountCA?[indexPath.row]
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegToTransactionPage", sender: indexPath.row)

        } else if indexPath.section == 4 {
            let strAccountCA = accTypeCA
            selectedCA = strAccountCA?[indexPath.row]
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegToTransactionPage", sender: indexPath.row)
        }

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "SegToTransactionPage") {
            if let transactionVC = segue.destination as? TransactionTableViewController {

                transactionVC.selectedPA = self.selectedPA
                transactionVC.selectedCA = self.selectedCA
                transactionVC.selectedInv = self.selectedInv
                transactionVC.selectedAss = self.selectedAss
                transactionVC.selectedLbty = self.selectedLbty

            }

        }
    }
```

```
# TransactionListTableViewController

var selectedPA : AccTypePA?
var selectedCA : AccTypeCA?
var selectedInv : AccTypeInv?
var selectedAss : AccTypeAss?
var selectedLbty : AccTypeLbty?


 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if section == 0 {
            print("Selected section 0 : \(section)")
            return selectedPA?.transPAList.count ?? 0
        } else if section == 1 {
            print("Selected section 1 : \(section)")
            return selectedCA?.transCAList.count ?? 0
        } else if section == 2 {
        print("Selected section 2 : \(section)")
        return selectedCA?.transCAList.count ?? 0
        } else if section == 3 {
        print("Selected section 3 : \(section)")
        return selectedCA?.transCAList.count ?? 0
        } else if section == 4 {
        print("Selected section 4 : \(section)")
        return selectedCA?.transCAList.count ?? 0
        }
        return transactions?.count ?? 1
        }
```

Comment: When the segue is called, you're only passing the row `performSegue(withIdentifier: `SegToTransactionPage", sender: indexPath.row)` each time. It doesn't know which section is, hence it's always 0. You also need to tell it what the section is `indexPath.section`

Answer (score 0):

Why You are using only `row` as `sender` instead whole `indexPath`? Then You have all info You need to do Your segue. And for me You should use model instead of `indexPath` for doing segue. This code is very error prone. 
Also You can use switch instead of `if else` in most of places.

And how second screen will know what You selected in first screen? You have to rethink Your implementation. In second screen You don't operate on section index from first one. Just send data model that You want to display and go from there.

Also, You don't unset previously set values as `self.selectedPA' and other "selected" vales.